# 5 minute bars using mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

i have collcted tick data in format like follows

```
"instrument","tick_time","ask","bid","askVol","bidVol"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:01","1.43676","1.43666","1.13","4.13"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:02","1.43676","1.43666","1.13","4.5"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:03","1.43674","1.43664","1.13","1.65"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:06","1.43675","1.43665","1.13","5.4"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:06","1.43677","1.43668","1.13","4.28"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:10","1.43676","1.43666","1.13","6.15"
"EUR/USD","2011-07-24 20:00:11","1.43679","1.43669","1.13","4.13"
```

NOW i am trying to create 5 minute bars out of it. i tried the following sql.

```
select    ROUND(tick_time / (60*5)) * 60 * 5 as bar_time,
          max(bid)  as high,
          min(bid) as low
from ticks
group by bar_time
```

I get the following data

```
"bar_time","high","low"
"20110724199900","1.43669","1.43661"
"20110724200200","1.4366","1.4358"
"20110724200500","1.43625","1.43579"
"20110724200800","1.4365","1.43608"
"20110724201100","1.43645","1.43601"
"20110724201400","1.43624","1.43573"
"20110724201700","1.43619","1.43591"
"20110724202000","1.43644","1.4359"
```

How do i do the following

1. format the bar_time in datetime format?
2. aggregate first and last data as columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a DateTime in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921362/how-to-round-a-datetime-in-mysql)

Comment: Another, possibly better, equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range

Comment: i would like to get the first bid for the grouping and the last bid for the grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other solution:

```
select 
    date_format( 
        date_sub(
            tick_time, 
            INTERVAL (extract(MINUTE from tick_time) % 5) MINUTE
        ), 
        "%m-%d%Y %H:%i"
    ) as  bar_time, 
    MAX(bid) AS high,
    MIN(bid) AS low
from ticks
group by bar_time
```

Comment: i get /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'ler_ts' in 'field list' */

Comment: Corrected - that needed to be tick_time

Comment: Great to hear that. Please also upvote/accept answers you like.

Answer (score 1):

1-  Format the bar_time in datetime format:

Assuming your [time format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is `%Y%m%d%H%i%s`, you can use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) mysql function:

```
select  str_to_date((ROUND(tick_time / (60*5)) * 60 * 5) , '%Y%m%d%H%i%s') as bar_time,
        max(bid)  as high,
        min(bid) as low
from ticks
group by bar_time
```

You may need to convert the first parameter of function (i.e. `ROUND(...)` ) to string.
Also, first row in your example contains time "20110724199900", are you sure about that 99 minutes?

2-  Didn't understand, can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: i would like to get the first bid for the grouping and the last bid for the grouping

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    
  STR_TO_DATE
  (
    CONCAT(
      LEFT(ROUND(tick_time / (60*5)) * 60 * 5,10)
      ,MID(ROUND(tick_time / (60*5)) * 60 * 5,10,2)/100*60
      ,RIGHT(ROUND(tick_time / (60*5)) * 60 * 5,2)/100*60
    )
    ,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s'
  ) AS bar_datetime
  , MAX(bid) AS high
  , MIN(bid) AS low
  , CONCAT(MAX(bid), ',', MIN(bid)) as max_min
FROM ticks
GROUP BY bar_datetime
```