# MYSQL Date Time Round To Nearest Hour

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a date time field in a MySQL database and wish to output the result to the nearest hour.

e.g. `2012-04-01 00:00:01` should read `2012-04-01 00:00:00`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a DateTime in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921362/how-to-round-a-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 53):

*Update: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330407/480943 is a better answer.*

---

You can do it with some date arithmetic:

```
SELECT some_columns,
    DATE_ADD(
        DATE_FORMAT(the_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"),
        INTERVAL IF(MINUTE(the_date) < 30, 0, 1) HOUR
    ) AS the_rounded_date
FROM your_table
```

Explanations:

- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format): `DATE_FORMAT(the_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")` returns the date truncated down to the nearest hour (sets the minute and second parts to zero).
- [MINUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute): `MINUTE(the_date)` gets the minute value of the date.
- [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if): This is a conditional; if the value in parameter 1 is true, then it returns parameter 2, otherwise it returns parameter 3. So `IF(MINUTE(the_date) < 30, 0, 1)` means "If the minute value is less than 30, return 0, otherwise return 1". This is what we're going to use to round -- it's the number of hours to add back on.
- [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add): This adds the number of hours for the round into the result.

Answer (score 46):

Half of the hour is a 30 minutes. Simply add 30 minutes to timestamp and truncate minutes and seconds.

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(timestamp_column, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') FROM table`

Answer (score 14):

soul's first solution truncates instead of rounding and the second solution doesn't work with Daylight Savings cases such as:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-03-11 2:14:00') - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-03-11 2:14:00'),300));
```

Here is an alternate method (1):

```
DATE_ADD(
    tick,
    INTERVAL (IF((MINUTE(tick)*60)+SECOND(tick) < 1800, 0, 3600) - (MINUTE(tick)*60)+SECOND(tick)) SECOND
)
```

If you don't need to worry about seconds you can simplify it like this (2):

```
DATE_ADD(
    tick,
    INTERVAL (IF(MINUTE(tick) < 30, 0, 60) - MINUTE(tick)) MINUTE
)
```

Or if you prefer to truncate instead of round, here is simpler version of soul's method (3):

```
DATE_SUB(tick, INTERVAL MINUTE(tick)*60+SECOND(tick) SECOND)
```

EDIT: I profiled some of these queries on my local machine and found that for 100,000 rows the average times were as follows:

- soul's `UNIXTIME` method: 0.0423 ms (fast, but doesn't work with DST)
- My method 3: 0.1255 ms
- My method 2:  0.1289 ms
- Ben Lee's `DATE_FORMAT` method: 0.1495 ms
- My method 1: 0.1506 ms

Comment: Tick from me because I just wanted to truncate

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is slow? I've never heard of that. Do you have a reference/benchmark for that? I can't find anything on google about `DATE_FORMAT` having poor performance, and nothing indicating that calls to  `MINUTE()` and `SECOND()` would be significantly faster than a call to `DATE_FORMAT`. In any case, shouldn't any performance difference be at the nanosecond level of magnitude -- essentially invisible/negligible for nearly every real-world purpose?

Comment: @BenLee I expected that manipulating strings and parsing the dates would be much slower than `MINUTE`/`SECOND`, but after profiling the two cases that isn't true. Your solution is even potentially a bit faster than mine (perhaps due to mine calling `MINUTE` and `SECOND` twice?). However, my example that omits the seconds is faster than `DATE_FORMAT`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: For anyone else's info, to truncate to other minute intervals (eg 15 mins): select `timestamp,date_sub(timestamp,interval (minute(timestamp) % 15)* 60  +second(timestamp) second)`...

Answer (score 8):

From [How to round a DateTime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921362/how-to-round-a-datetime-in-mysql/1921568#1921568):

> It's a little nasty when you do it with datetime data types; a nice candidate for a stored function.
>
> ```
> DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(time, INTERVAL MOD(MINUTE(time),5) MINUTE ), 
>          INTERVAL SECOND(time) SECOND)
> ```
>
> It's easier when you use UNIXTIME timestamps but that's limited to a 1970 - 2038 date range.
>
> ```
> FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time),300))
> ```
>
> Good luck.

Comment: Be careful with this. The unix time approach fails for datetimes that fall between the daylight savings time changes. For example:
`select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-03-11 2:14:00') - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-03-11 2:14:00'),300));`

Answer (score 7):

To round down to the current hour, select:

`FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column_name) / 3600) * 3600)`.

> The value is expressed in the current time zone [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way, since it also will use the least amount of resources-

```
date_add(date(date_completed), interval hour(date_completed) hour) as date_hr
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the next hour, that is `'2012-01-02 18:02:30'` will be converted into `'2012-01-02 19:00:00'`

```
TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURDATE(),timestamp_column_name),
    CURDATE())
```

Instead of `CURDATE()` you can use an arbitrary date, for example `'2000-01-01'`
Not sure if there could be problems using `CURDATE()` if the system date changes between the two calls to the function, don't know if Mysql would call both at the same time.

to get the *nearest* hour would be:

```
TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,
    ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CURDATE(),timestamp_column_name)/60)*60,
    CURDATE())
```

changing 60 by 15 would get the nearest 15 minutes interval,  using SECOND you can get the nearest desired second interval, etc.

To get the previous hour use `TRUNCATE()` or `FLOOR()` instead of `ROUND()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to round just time to next hour you may use this:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(
  ADDTIME(
    TIMEDIFF('16:15', '10:00'), '00:59:00'
  ),
  '%H:00:00'
)
```