# MySQL. How to get o'clock time from hour

Tags: mysql, time-format

I have a time datatype field "MyTimeField" in MySQL. So for example the value can be 10:30:00

I want to select the "o'clock time" in time format, so the output will 10:00:00

tried

```
 TIME_FORMAT(hour(MyTimeField),'%T')
```

but no luck, this returns 00:00:10

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680144/mysql-date-time-round-to-nearest-hour will probably steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Date Time Round To Nearest Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680144/mysql-date-time-round-to-nearest-hour)

Comment: close, but I don't have date as the other post. I only have a time field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the hour you could use

```
TIME_FORMAT(MyTimeField,'%H:00:00')
```

Comment: this returns 00:00:00 all the time

Comment: ditch the `HOUR` function; use the raw column as the first argument in the TIME_FORMAT function

Comment: TIME_FORMAT(MyTimeField,'%H:00:00') does the job!