Create bigger DATETIME intervals from little intervals and aggregate values with a SELECT query
I have a table in MySQL with stock data, that has the columns:



time
open
high
low
close
volume



I get an entry every 5 minutes. How do I get these values in an hourly interval instead of a 5 minute interval?
Effectively, I want to create a new table where the entries are aggregated to have 1 hourly row instead of 12 5 minute rows. The open and close values need to be the first and last of those in the 5 minute interval and high and low values need to be the max and min of those in the 5 minute interval. The volume just needs to be summed up.
I tried to achieve it with ChatGPT, but the query it produces throws a syntax error when I try it.
It gave me this:
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS hour_start,
    FIRST_VALUE(`open`) AS open,
    MAX(`high`) AS high,
    MIN(`low`) AS low,
    LAST_VALUE(`close`) AS close,
    SUM(`volume`) AS volume
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    hour_start;


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS open, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) AS low, LAST_VALUE(`clos' at line 3

I tried several times and also got queries that contained "OVER" as a keyword, but it also produced an error:
SELECT
    MIN(`time`) AS `time`,
    `open`,
    MAX(`high`) AS `high`,
    MIN(`low`) AS `low`,
    `close`,
    SUM(`volume`) AS `volume`
FROM
    (SELECT
         `time`,
         FIRST_VALUE(`open`) OVER (PARTITION BY HOUR(`time`) ORDER BY `time`) AS `open`,
         `high`,
         `low`,
         LAST_VALUE(`close`) OVER (PARTITION BY HOUR(`time`) ORDER BY `time`) AS `close`,
         `volume`
    FROM
        table) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    HOUR(`time`),
    DATE(`time`)
ORDER BY
    `time` ASC;


Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'subquery.open' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Do you know how to actually get this to work? I tried modifying these queries to make them work but had no success.

Had you a look at this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680144/mysql-date-time-round-to-nearest-hour  It could be worth investigating

Try not to over complicate it. Your intial query was almost what you want I think (but be careful with reserved words like "open" or "close" though, they have a special function and cannot be used as alias without quoting them. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O)
SELECT
    FIRST_VALUE(open) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H") ORDER BY time) AS first_open,
    LAST_VALUE(close) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H") ORDER BY time) AS last_close,
    MIN(low) AS min_low,
    MAX(high) AS max_high,
    SUM(volume) AS total_volume
FROM
    stock
GROUP BY
    HOUR(time),
    DATE(time);

If your MySQL version is below 8 (so you don't have access to first and last value), you could try the following:
SELECT
    (
      SELECT 
        s2.open 
      FROM 
        stock s2
      WHERE 
        DATE_FORMAT(s2.time, "%Y-%m-%d %H") = DATE_FORMAT(s1.time, "%Y-%m-%d %H")
      ORDER BY
        s2.time
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS first_open,
    (
      SELECT 
        s2.close 
      FROM 
        stock s2
      WHERE 
        DATE_FORMAT(s2.time, "%Y-%m-%d %H") = DATE_FORMAT(s1.time, "%Y-%m-%d %H")
      ORDER BY
        s2.time DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS last_close,
    MIN(s1.low) AS min_low,
    MAX(s1.high) AS max_high,
    SUM(s1.volume) AS total_volume
FROM
    stock s1
GROUP BY
    HOUR(s1.time),
    DATE(s1.time),
    first_open,
    last_close;


This is not actually what I want, as the resulting open value will not be the actual first value, but instead the lowest open value in the interval. The same goes for close, that should be the last close value, but results in the highest of all close values of the interval instead.

@DasZD Sorry, missed that in your first example. I have updated the answer, and added an alternative.

MySQL has the version 8.3.0 in my Docker container, but I still cannot execute your first query, it says there is a syntax error near "AS first_open...". Your second query does not throw an error, but it loads infinitely and does not actually finish querying.
