# SQL - get the next half an hour

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to be able to create a time in the following way:
for example if now() is between 09:00:00 to 09:29:00:00 so the new time will be 09:30:00.
If now() is between 09:30:00 to 09:59:00 so the new time will be 10:00:00.

Any idea how?

Comment: See [how-to-round-time-to-nearest-period-in-minutes](http://buysql.com/mysql/53-how-to-round-time-to-nearest-period-in-minutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

From [How to round a DateTime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921362/how-to-round-a-datetime-in-mysql/1921568#1921568):

It's a little nasty when you do it with datetime data types; a nice candidate for a stored function.

```
DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(time, INTERVAL MOD(MINUTE(time), 30) MINUTE), 
         INTERVAL SECOND(time) SECOND)
```

It's easier when you use UNIXTIME timestamps but that's limited to a 1970 - 2038 date range.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time), 1800))
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The below query may help you

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(current_timestamp(), '%i')  > 31 
                 and DATE_FORMAT(current_timestamp(), '%i')  < 59 
            WHEN 
                 CONCAT (DATE_FORMAT(current_timestamp(), '%H') + 1 , ':00:00' ) 
            ELSE CONCAT (DATE_FORMAT(current_timestamp(), '%H') , ':30:00' )  
            END;
```